# How can I permute the rows/columns of a Tensorflow 3-tensor?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a (N, 9, 9) shape tensorflow tensor T, and permutations Px, Py which might look like this: `[3 4 5 6 7 8 2 1 0]`, `[6 8 2 0 3 7 4 1 5]`.

I want to apply the permutation Px to the 1st axis of T, and Py to the 2nd axis. That is, I want to compute a tensor S defined by

S_i,j,k = T_i,Px(j),Py(k)

To use `tf.gather_nd` to construct S I need to construct an `indices` tensor such that

```
indices[i,j,k,0] = i
indices[i,j,k,1] = Px(j)
indices[i,j,k,2] = Py(k)
```

What's the cleanest way to construct `indices` (in Python)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I undestand your problem statement correctly, I believe this is what you need.

```
indices[:,:,:,0] = np.arange(indices.shape[0])
indices[:,:,:,1] = indices[:,Px(np.arange(indices.shape[1]),:,1]
indices[:,:,:,2] = indices[:,:,Py(np.arange(indices.shape[2]),2]
```

Hard to tell without a minimal reproducible.